# Java8 predicate for if else with return

Tags: java-8

How do I write a Java 8 predicate for the below  ?

```
 public boolean isArtOrNot(int aId) {
    if(aid <= 4) {
        return true;
    } else { 
    return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Generally, don’t write such nonsensical `if … else` statements. Just use `return aId <= 4;`. You can put the same expression into a predicate, e.g. `aId -> aId <= 4` or you use a method reference to your already existing method, `NameOfYourClass::isArtOrNot`. But without an actual problem to solve, there is no reason to “write a Java 8 predicate”…

Answer (score 2):

```
t -> t <= 4
```

e.g.

```
example.stream().filter(t -> t <= 4)
```

because the example is equivalent to:

```
public boolean isArtOrNot(int aId) {
    return aid <= 4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
IntPredicate predicate = i -> i <= 4;
```

Comment: How do I call this predicate ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Predicate<Integer> isArt = (i) -> i <= 4;
```

Answer (score -2):

To add on to [Marcel Jacques Machado's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39990036/3357935):

```
Predicate<Integer> isArt = (i) -> i <= 4;
```

Implementing the Predicate will be as follows:

```
if (isArt.test())  { .... .... }
```